# Xamarin.iOS cannot create/open storyboard

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, storyboard, visual-studio-2019

We have an issue with creating a **storyboard in Xamarin.iOS**. We have paired to Mac and on the VS GUI it says it is connected.
When we try to create (or open an existing storyboard in new project) we get the same error:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Error in the application.
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest(CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 235
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse](CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 252
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession() in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 111
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0() in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 116
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<>c__DisplayClass289_1`1.<EnsureSession>b__1(Task`1 t) in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 2070
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<>c__DisplayClass289_0`1.<EnsureSession>b__0() in E:\A\_work\79\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 2136
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[Truncated here]
```

The version of both VS on Windows 10 and Catalina is the latest one (cannot update anymore) and Xcode is version 11.3

I've read a lot of articles online saying to update and restart the IDE and it should be fine, but I cannot do anything...

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: When this sort of problems happens this is my goto solution: Delete bin/obj from Mobile and iOS projects, Restart both Mac and PC/Laptop, after this delete the app on the device if there's an older version on it, then Clean mobile, Clean iOS, rebuild Mobile, rebuild iOS (note: **rebuild it first, don't build/deploy in the device without rebuilding**), after this steps, if the problem was from connection/building, it should be gone

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais did all of this, few times, and it did not help at all...
I'm still getting the same MonoTouche.Design.Client error

Comment: @StefanSrbljanin Hi , have a try this steps :First ,if IP exists in pair list , right click to **Forget this Mac** . Second , you'd better reboot Mac. Third, click**Add Mac** to type the IP to re-connect .Finally , check whether storyboard shows well .

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais still doesn't work...
This issue is present on the Visual Studio for Mac as well if that's useful information.

Comment: @StefanSrbljanin OK, you can have a check with this [Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/storyboards/?tabs=macos#requirements) of Storyboard ,and have a try with xcode to check whether can open it .

Comment: have you tried creating the Storyboard in Mac and then replace the old storyboard?

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais, I've tried creating a new Xcode project with Storyboard and it normally opens and displays a UI to work on, but the error I'm getting is when I try to simulate anything
I get the error:
SpringBoard quite unexpectedly.

Comment: A fresh new XCode project gave you and error on the SpringBoard? how strange.. this makes me fell like it's the build host fault for making your storyboard corrupted, maybe do a fresh install of the xcode.. try to revert the VS2019 version to an older one with an compatible XCode Version

Comment: Try to update and the xamarin.ios

Comment: Okay, so, @RicardoDiasMorais, first of all, thank you for all of the support, you rock.
Secondly, the issue is, it seems, in macOS version.
I've talked with some of my coworkers who use a different type of software (Flash Builder) and he said he had similar issues with Catalina macOS.
So I switched back to Mojave, updated to 10.4.16. and installed Xcode and VSforMac and it finally works (or works for iPhone 8 iOS 13)

Comment: @StefanSrbljanin i'm very happy that you manage to find a solution, want me to right a solution or you add it yourself so others can see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, it seems, in macOS version. 
I've talked with some of my coworkers who use a different type of software (Flash Builder) and he said he had similar issues with Catalina macOS.
So I switched back to **Mojave**, **updated to 10.4.16**. and installed Xcode and VSforMac and it finally works (or works for iPhone 8 iOS 13)